# PrettyFaces redirect to RESTful url after login

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

I'm using PrettyFaces 3.3.3.  I have a requirement that if a user tries to view a page, but is not logged in, they are sent to the login page, and then redirected to the original page they wanted to view.  Just wondering what would be the best approach for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a security framework here. The basic idea is that you'd want to intercept the requested URL in your security filter, save it into the user's session, then once authentication is complete (e.g. user has submitted the form with their credentials, or whatever mechanism you're using) you retrieve the saved URL from the user's session and perform a 302 Redirect to it.

This is not something PrettyFaces will help you with directly, except that you can use it to capture the URL more easily using `PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance(request).getRequestURL();`

There is an article about this here: http://ocpsoft.org/java/jsf-java/spring-security-what-happens-after-you-log-in/

Using [OCPsoft Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) (core of PrettyFaces 4) you can do this programatically as well, and even do the authentication directly in your security rules or annotation config: https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettyfaces/blob/master/annotations/src/test/java/org/ocpsoft/prettyfaces/annotation/jaas/JaasRolesBean.java

This is an upcoming feature but is not yet complete - we would love feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I ended up using a phase listener, but will keep these options in mind for the not too distant future.